# How to deal with someone who refuses to admit they plagiarised?

Tags: friends

I'm going to keep this as unidentifiable as possible. My friend and I are making an app. We just submitted it today and were wondering what to write as the description for the app in the App Store.

I checked a similar app to see what they had written, then my friend sent me the description of our app that he wanted to send.

The two descriptions were virtually identical, down to the same punctuation being used. He had changed a few words but the sentences were clearly copied from the other app.

I immediately told him this and he was completely shocked and said he couldn't explain how it happened. I asked him if he had copied it which he vigorously denied, but the evidence was right there!

I sent him the two paragraphs side by side to which he said "YES I'VE SEEN IT!!!!!". I gave him an opportunity, I told him that I didn't care he had copied it, I know he'd been under a lot of stress and just wanted to get it out there as soon as possible so let's just change it and move on. He still refuses to admit that he copied it.

I changed the subject and we haven't talked about it since, but it's still in the back of my mind. Could he have done it by mistake? Maybe had the app description open while he was writing ours and been very tired?

How do I deal with him now? This might have been a one-off thing but nevertheless if it was plagiarism and he wasn't expecting to get caught then what happens if I catch him again? We're just starting out on a business venture together so this is kinda important I think!

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, doesn't sound like the person you want to be in business with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You caught him, he knows it, the problem was resolved before it was published so there was no real damage.

He probably knows that he won't get away with something like that again -- I'd just let it be water under the bridge. Without blaming him or directly saying that he plagiarized, say that since you're starting a business, the two of you need to be careful to keep your reputation clean, and do your due diligence before releasing anything. He's your friend, and the two of you have written an app together and are starting a business venture, there is no need to ruin that relationship over this by placing blame on him. Now if he does it again, then I would take more action.